# split a file name

Tags: python, string

How do i write a python script to split a file name

eg

```
LN0001_07272010_3.dat
```

and to rename the file to `LN0001_JY_07272010`?

also how do i place a '|' and the end of each line in this file(contents) each line is a record?

Comment: These are two separate questions, and you should ask them separately.

Comment: The question is really about splitting a string, which the answers have covered.  However, the title would lead me to things like [os.path.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split), which operates differently.

Comment: Probably the best answer to this question would be "read a introductory Python tutorial". Still, I posted an answer :-(

Answer (score 6):

```
fn = "LN0001_07272010_3.dat".split('_')
new_fn = '{0}_JY_{1}'.format(fn[0], fn[1])
```

**Update** forgot to add "JY" to `new_fn`

Comment: Doesn't get the "_JY_" into the new name.

Answer (score 3):

```
filename="LN0001_07272010_3.dat"
newfilename=filename.split("_")[0]+"_JY_"+filename.split("_")[1]

linearr=[]
for line in open(filename).readlines():
     linearr.append(line+"|")

f=open(newfilename, "w")
for line in linearr:
     f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
name = "LN0001_07272010_3.dat"                    
parts = name.split('_')  # gives you ["LN0001","07272010","3.dat"]    
newname = parts[0] + "_STUFF_" + parts[1] ... etc
```

For rename you can either use the python filesystem function,

Or you can use python print to spit out a set of rename commands for your OS, capture that to a batch/shell file and AFTER checking that it looks correct - run it.

```
print "mv ",name,newname   # gives; mv LN0001_07272010_3.dat LN0001_JY_07272010
```

Comment: jesse's solution with the {0} is neater - but with a script it's often better to have simple and readable.

Comment: if you find it unreadable then you should familiarize yourself with that syntax: it's the preferred string formatting solution as of Python 3 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: @Jesse - I was just making the point that the most obvious, even if not the shortest, quickest or most elegent - is often the optimal solution for a script that is going to be run once.

Comment: sorry not trying to be a dick. I'm just saying that readability is to some extent a matter of taste, and as this is preferred way to format strings, one should acquire a taste for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Because in-place operations are usually a **bad idea**, here is a code that creates a new file leaving the original unchanged:

```
fn = "LN0001_07272010_3.dat"
fn1, fn2 = fn.split("_")[:2]
new_fn = "_".join([fn1, "JY", fn2])
open(new_fn, "w").writelines(line.rstrip()+"|\n" for line in open(fn))
```

Comment: Probably bad choice if LN0001_07272010_3.dat is a multi-gb database file?

Comment: Edit - sorry ignore the comment, I thought you meant do a line-line copy as an alternative to a rename.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = 'LN0001_07272010_3.dat'
new_file_name = '{0}_JY_{1}'.format(file_name.split('_')[0], file_name.split('_')[1])
```